# Python: Increasing one number in a list by one

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a program that returns the frequency of a certain pattern. My frequency list is initially a list of zeros, and I want to increase a certain zero by one depending on the pattern. I have tried the code below, but it does not work.

```
FrequencyArray[j] = FrequencyArray[j]+1
```

Is there another way to increase one element of the list by 1 without affecting the other elements?

Comment: Explain what exactly is the problem. *Does not work* doesn't help much

Comment: Your statement should certainly work. Please add more context to your problem. May be j is not referring to the element you want to refer to?

Comment: My program was not giving me an output, but I took another look at my program, and I was able to fix it. j was referring to the output from another program. I realized that the problem was with the other program that I was referring to. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your approach should work, this would be the alternative:

```
FrequencyArray[j] += 1
```

Example:

```
>>> zeros = [0, 0, 0]
>>> zeros[1] += 1
>>> zeros
[0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!